# Wrapping jquery $.ajax in RSVP.Promise blows up the whole application

Tags: jquery, ajax, ember.js, ember-app-kit

**UPDATE 1:** *Added another surprisingly non-working code sample*

**UPDATE 2:** *I went back to start and did a rewrite of my newly implemented logic - it works now*

---

I'm using `Ember.js` along with the (now deprecated) `ember-app-kit` layout and conventions. The main libraries versions are:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.4.0
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.0
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

As I had the intention to keep all my `Ajax` requests in one place I came up with an `AjaxManager` class which handeled all my requests with the following code:

```
function async (requestObj, successCallback, errorCallback) {

  requestObj.async = true; // just to be sure it's really asynchronous

  return $.when($.ajax(requestObj)).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
}
```

Now, as I got further and my code evolved I wanted to wrap this in a `Ember.RSVP.Promise` object, just to have some convenience when calling it from my `model` hooks and the like. So I did the following:

```
function promisedAsync (requestObj) {

  requestObj.async = true; // just to be sure it's really asynchronous

  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    requestObj.success = function (data) {
       resolve(data);
    };

    requestObj.error = function () {
      reject(arguments)
    };

    $.ajax(requestObj);
  });
}
```

But, what happens now is that my first `Ember.RSVP.Promise` gets resolved as expected, but all further Promises remain unresolved/unrejected which means it hangs the whole application and drives Chrome to blow up the page thread and gather more and more RAM (which is summing up frequently and is only stoppable by killing the process).

So, basically `Ember.RSVP.Promise` blows up `$.ajax`! I also tried it with `Ember.RSVP.defer()`, or using the `jqXHR.beforeSend` method get the promise/deferred resolved/rejected but it's always the same: **the first promise gets resolved/rejected, all others are hanging** and will never come up again...

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried it with plain `XMLHttpRequest`, leaving `jQuery.ajax` behind, and an `RSVP.defer()` deferred object, but it's giving me *the same result*:

```
var set = Ember.set,
    get = Ember.get,
    RSVP = Ember.RSVP;
//....
// some application code
//...

promisedAsync: function (ajaxData) {
    var url = get(ajaxData, 'url'),
        method = get(ajaxData, 'type').toUpperCase(),
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), // developing on Chrome, no IE needed (until now) :)
        data = get(ajaxData, 'data'),
        deferred = RSVP.defer();

    if (method === 'GET') {
      url = this._prepareUrl(url, data); // takes the data and concatenates it so that the params are in the URL
    }

    xhr.open(method, url);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        var response;

        try {
          response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            deferred.resolve(response);
          } else {
            deferred.reject(response);
          }

        } catch (e) {
          deferred.reject(e);
        }
      }
    };

    xhr.onabort = function () {
      deferred.reject('aborted');
    };

    if (method === 'GET') {
      xhr.send(null);
    } else {
      xhr.send(data);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

As I ran out of ideas and not a single char of error code or something else came out of the dev tools console I finally reverted my huge pile of code and made a hard reset. I implemented the code in smaller steps/commits/chunks and now it works! I have *absolutely no idea* what was causing this issue as the code is pretty much the same...

---

<strike>Has anybody run into a similar issue or can give me some advice or hint in the right direction?</strike>

Comment: how are you calling `promiseAsync` ? It seems to work fine here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wewenigo/1/edit , however i would be careful when calling multiple times `promiseAsync` with the same requestObj.

Comment: @melc thanks for the jsbin sample - I'm calling it the exact same way you do in your example... I'm perplex and at a loss

Comment: @melc please see my newest update - I'm out of ideas now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, only a revert & rewrite did the trick - sorry for all you future devs running into something similar, but there's no real solution to my problem other than doing it again. This drove me nuts!

I'll accept this answer as the solution to my problem so that this could be closed.

Comment: Hi @herom ! What is the solution which you found? How does your final wrapped code look like?

Comment: Is it something like this one? https://gist.github.com/knownasilya/5975538

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue either, for testing sake it'd be good to wrap it in a `Ember.run` statement, here's a copy of how Ember Data does it (pretty much the same as yours).

```
 ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
    var adapter = this;

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      hash = adapter.ajaxOptions(url, type, hash);  // this is your requestObj

      hash.success = function(json) {
        Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
      };

      hash.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        Ember.run(null, reject, adapter.ajaxError(jqXHR));
      };

      Ember.$.ajax(hash); // this is the same thing as $.ajax
    }, "DS: RestAdapter#ajax " + type + " to " + url); // they name their promise
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer - I don't know what's going on as I tried it without `$.ajax` with plain `XMLHttpRequest` Object and the `onreadystatechange` method gets never called, too. this is absoluteley weird, as I see in my server logs and at wireshark that the response is actually sent with valid data... I'm pulling out my hair - this is a real PIA :(

Comment: what's really odd is the thing that, whatever implementation I choose, **the first request fulfills (resolves) the returned Promise) - all others are hanging!

Comment: I think it's likely that something else is foobaring your promises. For kicks and giggles have you tried switching Ember versions just to eliminate an issue with that version?

Comment: yes, I tried everything from up- and downgrading Ember and all further used libraries, but in the end, just a complete rewrite of my structure helped to remove this really strange behaviour. so, I went back to start (git, I love you!) and reproduced my steps in smaller chunks and commits - now everything works like expected o_O - thanks a lot for your help :)